# javascript 選択されたタブの太文字とbgカラーを変更する方法を教えてください。

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeTab(tabname) {
        document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tab3').style.display = 'none';
        if(tabname) {
            document.getElementById(tabname).style.display = 'block';               
        }
    }
</script>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a onclick="ChangeTab('tab1'); return false;" class="tab1" href="#tab1">1Channel ~ 2Channel</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="ChangeTab('tab2'); return false;" class="tab2" href="#tab2">4Channel ~ 8Channel</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="ChangeTab('tab3'); return false;" class="tab3" href="#tab3">16Channel</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab" id="tab1">内容</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">内容</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">内容</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ChangeTab('tab1');          
</script>
```

---

上記の内容で選択されたliを太文字とbgカラーを変更するにはどうすればいいですか。

Answer (score 1):

tabnameを番号にかえて　bgカラーが変更するように書いてみました。（太文字も同じ要領で付けて下さい）

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        ChangeTab(0);
    }
    function ChangeTab(no) {
        document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tab3').style.display = 'none';
        var elem_li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for(var i=0;i<elem_li.length;i++){
            elem_li[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
        elem_li[no].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.getElementById('tab'+(parseInt(no)+1)).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a onclick="ChangeTab(0); return false;" class="tab1" href="#tab1">1Channel ~ 2Channel</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="ChangeTab(1); return false;" class="tab2" href="#tab2">4Channel ~ 8Channel</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="ChangeTab(2); return false;" class="tab3" href="#tab3">16Channel</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab" id="tab1">内容1</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">内容2</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3">内容3</div>
```